# How to add items in top of scroll view in qt5 qml

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, qml, qt5

Hello i am working on a serious chat application using qt5 qml and Python.

I am adding chats dynamically to scrollview using

Qt.createQmlObject

But I want to load old chats when scrollbar reached to top.
So how can i add those chats in top of scrolllview instead of adding in end ?

```
ScrollView{
    Column{
      #dynamic chats here
    }
}
```

I am adding those dynamic chats in column layout.
Sorry if i couldn't explain that much .Thank You !

Comment: Did you try watching for when your scrollbar's position == 0?

Comment: @JarMan I think you didn't understand my problem. I can detect when scrollbar reached to end but my problem is how can i dynamically add new items in top of all items so that it will look like old chats loading

Comment: You dynamically add objects by calling createQmlObject, but you already know that. So I'm not sure what your question is. Is your question how to put them at the top of the list instead of the bottom?

Comment: Why wont you use a `Listview` and insert items to the top? You wont even need to create Items dynamically.

Comment: Yes my question is how to put items at the top of list instead of bottom. Can you give me an example of  how to add new items dynamically to the listview